# How to handle zeros before FFT convolution / deconvolution?

Tags: fft, python, convolution, deconvolution

I would like to calculate the input function (unknown) by  deconvolution of the output and the "system response" signals.

- The output is a finite signal from a measure device so it presents a certain amount of noise and values close to zero at the beggining and the end.
- The "system response" is also a finite signal with zeros in both ends.

I already tried with the direct deconvolution method (scipy.deconvolve), however the result is affected by the noise.

Then I tried Wiener deconvolution, however the result is shifted (probably because  of circular convolution and the zeros at the beggining of the signals...)

**Question:**

How should I perform the zero padding ? Do i need to pad both signals?

In most of the examples that I found the first non zero value of the kernel is located in the first element of the array, however this is not my case.  how I can take in to account the zeros at the beggining and the end of each of the signals?

How to handle the sharp changes between the zero and the non zero parts of both signals? (seems to affect the result of the wiener deconvolution)

Comment: did you try dividing FFTs ? Is the spectrum of system response broad band enough to reconstruct the input ?

Comment: When using the FFT, the origin (middle) of the kernel must be at the first element of the array, with the left half wrapping around to the end of the array. If you get this wrong, then the result of the (de-)convolution will be shifted. See here for an explanation in 2D: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54877892/7328782